# Is there an "arbitrary HTML" equivalent to Lightbox with partial opacity for mask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Lightbox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) nicely presents a lightbox that

(a) works for images and does not appear to be documented for non-image usage, and

(b) has full opacity for the ?div? that overlays everything but the lightbox.

I would like a similar program that

(a) works for arbitrary HTML, or at least a div containing CSS positioned div's, images, and text, and

(b) has something like 50% opacity for the overlay div so that the background is still clearly visible, only dimmed and deemphasized.

What are my best options for that?

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 2):

Not usually into answering on software recommendations, but I think [GreyBox](http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/) fits the bill for you here.

The examples on that very page illustrate a semi-transparent overlay (easy to change in most of these things, however) and launching it to contain images, websites and the like.

Answer (score 1):

[Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) - Will provide that feature set for you.

Comment: Fancybox is non-free (non-libre, and non-gratis for commercial use). Anything like it that's free?

Answer (score 0):

(a) you can solve this yourself with iframes. But if you need a framework(it's not a 'program' is it) try dojo. You need to read a bit to get it running like you want to if you want clean js code, for a short hack however dojos dialogs are easy and fast too use.

(b) you dont change your javascript framework if you dont like the style. That's like changing from word to open office because you dont like the standard font. simply include this a css file containing this after(!) the css file of lightbox:

```
#lightboxOverlay {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```